# C#/Unity: Connect to a TCP Socket on another Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, sockets

I'm developing an application in Unity, which reads from a TCP stream.
Currently the reading is done in a seperate thread and a while loop. All works fine, except that the thread continues running although the main program is closed.
I tried using Coroutines from Unity, but I cannot connect to the server then.

How are those cases handled? Do I use something other than threads or Coroutines? Do I check in the while loop if the main Thread is still running?

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in the meantime:

My thread ist started from a MonoBehaviour class. There you can implement the methods OnDestroy() or OnApplicationQuit().
I'm using the OnDestroy() Method to set a boolean value to false, which stops the while loop and my thread finishes. Alternatively you can call Abort() on the thread.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).